# How to choose specific list line based on time in javascript or jQuery or angular?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, angular, cordova

I am fetching JSON file and bind it to list items. I have added name/value pair to json for each line as audioTime/"time like 0, 5 ,10 in seconds form".

I am using media plugin in a cordova application and doing functionality something like as follow :

```
setInterval(() => {
  if (this.loadedFullData == false) {
    this.data = this.dataMain; // data is large so I have sliced data into slices in this.data variable. Now bind full data to sliced data variable. I think it takes 2-5 secs based on devices and freeze app for 1-2 secs.
    this.loadedFullData = true;
  }
  this.mediaObject.getCurrentPosition().then((currentTime) => {
    this.mediaCurrentTime = currentTime;
    let divToUpdate = 'Eng' + Math.floor(currentTime);
    if ($('#' + divToUpdate).length) {
      $('#' + this.oldDivId).css({
        'font-weight': 'normal'
      });
      $('#' + divToUpdate).css({
        'font-weight': 'bold',
      });
      window['customComponent'].component.content.scrollTo(0, document.getElementById(divToUpdate).offsetTop - (screen.height / 3), 1000);
      this.oldDivId = divToUpdate;
    }
  });
}, 1000);
```

Now issue is : It goes to right line but sometime goes to wrong one. What is the issue? I am puzzled. Is there any other way???

Comment: `$('#' + divToUpdate).length` will evaluate to `true` for any div that is not `null` or `undefined`. Maybe the problem lies there?

Comment: So, What can I do? Can you edit code for me, bro?

Comment: I have tried it like : 
 if ($('#' + divToUpdate).length>0)

but same issue then again.

Comment: I am guessing more than I know. I was hoping to shed some light on your attempt :P I do not fully understand what you are trying to achieve. I am guessing you want to scroll to a specific list-element after all the data is loaded. And that based on the current time.

Comment: Yes, You have got my point 100% right.

Yes :- >  I want to scroll to a specific list-element after all the data is loaded. And that based on the current time

Comment: Maybe try: `divToUpdate.scrollIntoView();`

Comment: you say sometimes correct one, and sometimes wrong one. Can you give an example of what is right and what is wrong?

Comment: Problem arrives when large json file loaded approx. more than 25000 lines data. If it is less then 5000 lines then everything goes well. Proper line is highlighted even user seek time to 1 mintues, 2 mintues, 2:30 mintues and vice versa.

Comment: I see. I am sorry I cannot be of any help. Maybe someone else are able to help you. If you are able to make a plunkr or something similar, it might be easier to help you.

Comment: Means : Sometime I seek time it highlight right line, sometimes seeking on same time it highlight wrong line. Got it?

Comment: divToUpdate.scrollIntoView();

It is only scrolling same as I have done using other way.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is this line

`if ($('#' + divToUpdate).length)`

If you know that your element has the id on the form *"Eng"+someNumber* like this:

`let divToUpdate = 'Eng' + Math.floor(currentTime);`

Then you do not have to check the length. You might end up with a nullpointer.

How about

```
this.mediaCurrentTime = currentTime;
var divToUpdate = 'Eng' + Math.floor(currentTime);
var divToUpdateEl = document.getElementById(divToUpdate);
if (divToUpdateEl) {
    $('#' + this.oldDivId).css({
        'font-weight': 'normal'
    });
    $('#' + divToUpdate).css({
        'font-weight': 'bold',
    });
    divToUpdateEl.scrollIntoView();
    this.oldDivId = divToUpdate;
}
```

Comment: Still not works! I have full quality mp3 file to play. It works. Some time on low quality file, when we seek time it changes it's location on same time.

Comment: I have do it as same I used before, Audio was corrupted, I have changed the audio.

Comment: Yes. 
See my this comment : - Problem arrives when large json file loaded approx. more than 25000 lines data. If it is less then 5000 lines then everything goes well. Proper line is highlighted even user seek time to 1 mintues, 2 mintues, 2:30 mintues and vice versa.

But it was not json file issue, It was audio file issue.